# Does MS Azure have a way to package up and deploy whole sets of services?

Tags: azure

For example, if I have a whole stack of services on Azure - a database, redis, front end web app, back end web app, storage, and whatever else...and I want to be able to package this up in a way that I can easily deploy a whole new clone of that set of services easily. Spin up a new dev environment, or QA, or as a backup in case production goes down, whatever.

Comment: Looks like resource manager might be the ticket. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-overview

Comment: Yes ARM is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of CICD (Continuous Integration Continuous Deployment). The most common way with Azure (without 3rd party) is to construct ARM template to deploy in different environment such as dev, testing, staging or production. In ARM template you need to define different resource types, its name and properties in JSON format. If you haven't worked in ARM template, here is the article to get started https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-create-first-template and also from here with Visual Studio https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/vs-azure-tools-resource-groups-deployment-projects-create-deploy

In more complex environment and deployment, you might consider looking into another 3rd options such as Jenkin, Ansible, Chef, Octopus, Puppet which gives you comprehensive CICD solution.